# Autofilter Macro, then copy visible data ONLY and paste to next available row

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a macro that automatically chooses values in an autofilter based on a date.

This works great. However I need it to copy ONLY the visible cells with data and paste it into the NEXT available row in worksheet called "referral".

```
Sub Referral()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheets("Raw")
        Sheets("Raw").ShowAllData
        Sheets("Raw").Range("A1:BK1").AutoFilter Field:=14, _
        Criteria1:=Format(Sheets("Main").Range("E13").Value + 15, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        Sheets("Raw").Range("A1:BL50000").Copy
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Sub Referral()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Raw")

    .ShowAllData
    .Range("A1:BK1").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=Format(Sheets("Main").Range("E13").Value + 15, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    'this is generic, you may need to adjust this based on your sheet and data needs
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

End With

'goes to cell below last used cell in column A
Sheets("referral").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Raw").AutoFilterMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'don't forget to turn on your ScreenUpdating again!

End Sub
```