# Excel Filtering and Copying in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I'm working on a VBA script that pulls a range of dates from Access, then filters the data and creates a chart based on the filtered data.  The filtered data will be going to a separate sheet where the chart will be pulling its data from .  I can get data out of Access with a SQL statement, but my `AutoFilter` in Excel is erroring out. Here is what I have...

```
Sheet3.Range("F4:F500").AutoFilter(, "Riveter 01").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A5")
```

It gives an app-defined or object-defined error and I can't figure out why.  Is this the proper way or is there an easier way?

PS:  This filter will happen with 22 unique machines so I was planning on running a loop for each machine.  If that is not the fastest or proper way please let me know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to split this into two parts. Filter and then copy/ paste. See below:

```
With Sheet3
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With .Range("F4:F500")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Riveter 01"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A5")
    End With
End With
```

to remove the filter:

```
On Error Resume Next
    Sheet3.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0
```

On Error Resume Next is for when there is no filter present to skip the error. Please note the use of Sheet3 and Sheet2 for those looking for a generic solution.

Comment: This code works!  What I'm not sure about now is a) why it takes the cell from "F4" and copies it since it is a different machine.  It even copied "F3" when I changed the range.  b) how to grab data in the same row (so two cells to the right, grab the time each machine was up and running that day and then copy it instead of the machine name.)  Thank you for the help!!

Comment: it takes F4 as that is in your Range. To grab more data look at using .CurrentRegion of your Range. You will need to create a new question with more detail as it cannot be solved in the comments section. Include the data, which rows the data is in and what data you want to copy.

Comment: How do you then remove the filter?

Comment: added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to do this in 2 separate steps:

1. filter the data
2. copy the filtered data to another sheet

The answer here has an excellent example of how to do this: [Autofilter Macro, then copy visible data ONLY and paste to next available row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903878/autofilter-macro-then-copy-visible-data-only-and-paste-to-next-available-row)

Comment: I have tried adding a new Sub and modifying that code, but I'm still recieving a 1004 app-defined or object-defined error.