# Getting filtered list in another sheet in Excel by formula

Tags: excel-formula, filtering

Is there a way to copy filtered list to another sheet using formula? I know how to copy visible cells, but I need to do it by formula.

Comment: You can accomplish that with `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`

Answer (score 0):

just change A:A to whatever column your list is in and change the destination :)

```
Sheet1.range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")
```

ps next time just google excel vba whatever you're looking for, it brought me here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13956899/6868389

Comment: Well, my question is not about vba. My question is about using plain Excel formulas. I know people do different tricks with Small and other formulas. Thought, maybe someone's got a solution here.   
And I do google first, please believe me.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in columns **A** and **B** that we are going to filter.  In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(3,B2:B2)=0,MIN($C$1:C1)-1,SUBTOTAL(3,$B$2:$B2))
```

and copy down:

[image]

If we filter column **B** for the *2'* s, we see:

[image]

Even filtered, column **C** still shows the simple sequential sequence.  We can now easily retrieve data from the visible rows using `MATCH()` and `INDEX()`:

In `Sheet2` cell **A1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$1:A$22,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Sheet1!C$1:C$22,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

We can retrieve info from other columns in the same fashion.

*Another good place to post non-programming questions like this is:*

[superuser](https://superuser.com/)