# Excel- VBA filter and move results

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I am trying to set up a vba code to filter a sheet of data and cut rows containing specific values to other sheets. The snippet below is for one of these filters. So far I am struggling to debug this line.

```
myRange.Offset(1).Resize(myRange.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Cut
```

I keep getting an error that I cannot run this on multiple sections. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub MoveButton()
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set myRange = Range(Range("A1"), Range("Z" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
myRange.Resize(1).AutoFilter
myRange.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="Closed"
myRange.Offset(1).Resize(myRange.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlVisible).Cut
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets("Closed").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
myRange.AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Ok I this is what I got using record macro. Now I'm just not sure how to change the ranges so that they autoselect all of the filtered rows and copy and paste them to the next wmpty row on the next sheet.

```
Sub MoveCancelled()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$Z$20").AutoFilter Field:=13,Criteria1:="Closed"
    Rows(3).Select ' Selecting the row to copy, but it could be more than just one row.
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Closed").Select
    Rows(114).Select ' Selecting the paste location at the bottom of the next sheet.
    ActiveSheet.Paste


End Sub
```

I found this thread and ended up scrapping all my other efforts.

[Autofilter Macro, then copy visible data ONLY and paste to next available row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903878/autofilter-macro-then-copy-visible-data-only-and-paste-to-next-available-row)

This solution worked perfectly.

Comment: First run the exercise manually with the *Macro Recorder* turned on.........then examine the resulting code.

Comment: Not sure why you are resizing before you filter, you should be filtering from the Header Row

Comment: I tried using the Macro Recorder. I added that code into the message above. I am not sure how to make the ranges automatically select all filtered rows to cut/copy or to select the first empty row in the closed sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is the .cut operation giving you grief, try this one,

```
Sub MoveButton()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, MyRng As Range, rws As Long, Frng As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Proposals")
    With ws
        rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set MyRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(rws, "Z"))
        MyRng.AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="Closed"
        Set Frng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(rws, "Z")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Frng.Copy sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Frng.EntireRow.Delete
    ws.AutoFilterMode = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good, but I get an error that says this will not work on overlapping sections. Not sure what that means exactly.

Comment: Either do I, what haven't you told us?