# Optimizing code for copy and pasting with ranges that change

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code here that dynamically filters all data in a big set that grows every day and then resets at the beginning of the month, selects what I filtered for, copies it, and pastes it in another file.  Again, it's dynamic in that it doesn't matter how big the list is.  There is a header row on row 1.  This code, however, is not optimal because it's full of activate and select.  I'm at a loss of how to rewrite this without using the clipboard and without using select.  Here is the code.

```
    Workbooks(DataFileName).Activate
    Sheets(twtsumdivdata).Activate
                On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=shopcol1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(FilterRange2), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Do Until ActiveCell.Height <> 0
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Loop
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(ShopFileName).Activate
    Sheets(twtsumdivsheet).Range(target2).Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Here's something I have tried, but no luck.  I need to capture the whole data set that is filtered and put it in another workbook.

```
Dim Src As Range, Dst As Range
Worksheets(twtsumdivdata).Rows("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=shopcol1,   Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(FilterRange2), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Set Src = Workbooks(DataFileName).Worksheets(twtsumdivdata).Range("A2").End(xlDown, xlRight).Value
Set Dst = Workbooks(ShopFileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(Src.Rows.Count, Src.Columns.Count)
Dst.Value = Src.Value
```

Another thought is to try just grabbing all the visible cells after filtering.  I'm still a little unsure how I'd do that though.

Comment: I don't believe this is a [mcve].  But for autofilter and copy visible there are lots of SO examples e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903878/autofilter-macro-then-copy-visible-data-only-and-paste-to-next-available-row

Answer (score 0):

Removing `.Value` from line `Set Src = Workbooks...` might solve the problem. But I'd rather do it this way:

```
Dim Src As Range, Dst As Range
Worksheets(twtsumdivdata).Rows("1:1").AutoFilter Field:=shopcol1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(FilterRange2), Operator:=xlFilterValues

Set Dst = Workbooks(ShopFileName).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Set Src = Workbooks(DataFileName).Worksheets(twtsumdivdata).UsedRange
Src.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Dst
```

This will copy all visible cells including header row in the same format.

If you want to copy only data without header row, replace last line with this:

```
Intersect(Src, Src.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Dst
```