# Copy and paste data between workbooks depending on drop-down choice

Tags: excel, vba

Just a quick one, I have coded a piece of VBA that copies and pastes data between two workbooks. However, I would like to be able to copy specific data across rather than the entire table. So workbook "x" I would like to filter column 'L' by a choice of a drop down box in workbook "y" - field "P14".

how would I do this, so that whatever the user chooses it filters and pastes that data into workbook y.

Code below for what I've done so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim p As String

    Set p = y.Worksheets("Title").Cells(14, "P").Value
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\name\Desktop\Project
    Autonetics\CoreData")
    'x.Worksheets("Xero").Range("L1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:="p"
    With Xero
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("L:L")
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:="p"
            .SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)
        End With
    End With
    Set y = ThisWorkbook
    x.Worksheets("Xero").Range("A1:L100000").Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    y.Worksheets("Costings").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

    x.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you looked into [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)? Maybe even [`Range.AdvancedFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter) which should be faster =)

Comment: @JvdV I have indeed but I am not sure how to use the auto filter function, but that was the way I was thinking of using. How would i program this using autofilter

Comment: Recording a macro could be helpful. There are also examples here on SO of how to use `AutoFilter`.

Comment: @BigBen Hi BigBen, not too sure how to use the autofilter function - I can use macros but do you perhaps have a link to the autofilter example on SO

Comment: You should store the value from WB Y in a variable (String or whatever) and use this variable as input criteria in  Range.AutoFilter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903878/autofilter-macro-then-copy-visible-data-only-and-paste-to-next-available-row

Comment: @Daghan Thank you, will try and see what I can do, I have tried doing this way but struggled. Can anyone help with some code example

Comment: @BigBen Thank you, will check now. If you have any code example that would be tailored for my code that would be great because I have looking into autofilters but cant get my head around it.

Comment: @Daghan  I have edited to code, am I on the right lines?

Comment: @BigBen I have edited to code, am I on the right lines?

Comment: @JvdV I have edited to code, am I on the right lines?

Comment: You're getting there :). Now you need to copy the visible cells - see the link I provided earlier.

Comment: I would start with `Set`-ting your `Workbook` variables first, meaning `y` is not initialized (only later on in your code). If you want to see how you could handle some `AutoFilter`, than you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58889516/9758194) an interesting read. It includes how you can check for results first to prevent errors.

Comment: @BigBen I'm struggling, can't get my head around it

Comment: @BigBen I have edited the code above but still not working, is it possible if you could help with some code? Really can't figure it out

Comment: @JvdV I have edited the code above, is there any chance you can help out with some code? I am struggling and cant seem to get it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something for you to work with. Personally I'm not such a `On Error` fan, but it would be legitimate use inside to check for a returned error when using `SpecialCells`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lc As Long, lr As Long
Dim rng As Range, str As String

'Set your two workbooks
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\name\Desktop\ProjectAutonetics\CoreData")

'Set your two worksheets
Set sht1 = wb1.Worksheets("Title")
Set sht2 = wb2.Worksheets("Xero")

'Get your criteria ready
str = sht1.Range("P14").Value

'Get your range to filter ready
With sht2
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lr, lc))
End With

'Apply filter and act if any hits
rng.AutoFilter 12, str
If rng.SpecialCells(12).Cells.Count > rng.Rows(1).Cells.Count Then
    rng.SpecialCells(12).Copy sht1.Cells(1, 1)
End If

'Close your second workbook
wb2.Close False

End Sub
```

I been quite extensive in the hope you can clearly see what is going on in this code.

Good luck.

Comment: That's great to hear. Glad it's been helpfull @Daisy